# Double returning NaN but not all the time

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I am baffled here. I have a function to return a double, sometimes it returns the correct value, but most of the times it return NaN. From my understanding NaN is returned when we have something like 0/0. Below is the function returning NaN, all it's variables are declared as doubles.

```
public double SuperiorValue(List<double> l)
    {
        valueKn[0] = 0;
        valueKn[1] = 0;
        valueKn[2] = 1.69;
        valueKn[3] = 1.18;
        valueKn[4] = 0.95;
        valueKn[5] = 0.82;
        valueKn[6] = 0.75;
        valerKn[7] = 0.67;
        valueKn[8] = 0.63;
        valueKn[9] = 0.58;
        valueKn[10] = 0.561;
        valueKn[11] = 0.542;
        valueKn[12] = 0.523;
        valueKn[13] = 0.504;
        valueKn[14] = 0.485;
        valueKn[15] = 0.466;
        valueKn[16] = 0.447;
        valueKn[17] = 0.428;
        valueKn[18] = 0.409;
        valueKn[19] = 0.39;
        valueKn[20] = 0.382;

        Xm = (l.Sum()) / (l.Count);

        for (int i = 0; i < l.Count; i++)
        {
            sumTemporary = l[i] - Xm;
            sum = sum + sumTemporary;
        }

        kn = valueKn[l.Count];

        sx = Math.Sqrt((1 / l.Count - 1) * (sum * sum));
        Vx = sx / Xm;
        Xksup = Xm * (1 + kn * Vx);
        Xkinf = Xm * (1 - kn * Vx);

        return Xksup;

    }
```

What baffles me even more is that never is the list made of less than 3 elements and greater than 15, and it still often returns NaN but like I said sometimes it returns the correct value. Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: Did you use the debugger?

Comment: Is `valerKn[7] = 0.67;` a typo? Note `r` in `valerKn`

Comment: This code won't compile, and you haven't given us any input value that might cause `NaN` with your expectation otherwise.

Comment: @xanatos only if x is 0 - otherwise you'll get `PositiveInfinity` or `NegativeInfinity`

Comment: Bas , I do not know how to use it unfortunately for me.
Dmitry yes that was a typo, my bad, sleepy !
Charles, the code compiles but return NaN.....

Comment: Seems like you should also be checking if `l` is empty, null, or has more than 20 values up front.

Comment: Like I said the input list L is never empty, has more than 3 elements and maximum 15 elements. Henk's answer below made me want to take elementary school  math back !

Comment: @BogdanU Those cases wouldn't cause `Nan`, but would cause null reference, index out of bounds, and division by zero exceptions.  It's still a good practice to check your assumptions up front to make debugging easier if you ever did pass a null, empty or more than 20 item list to this method.

Comment: @BogdanU You can use the debugger by adding a breakpoint and making sure your program is running in debug. Presumably you are using visual studio, in which case you can see an empty bar on the left hand side of the code panel, if you click in here on the line you want to look at it will give you a breakpoint. Alternatively you can select the line you want to start at and press F9. Next time you run your app in debug mode it will stop here. Learning how to use the debugger and debugging in general is a useful skill to have a look at this website http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging. Good luck.

Comment: @Keithin8a thank you, will definitely have a look at it !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at

```
Math.Sqrt((1 / l.Count - 1) * (sum * sum))
```

The `1 / l.Count` is an integer division, it will be `0` for all `l.Count > 1` and then you are computing `Sqrt(-1 * (sum * sum))` .

But `(1.0 / l.Count - 1)`  would still be negative, you probably want `(1.0 / (l.Count - 1))`

The fix is then:

```
Math.Sqrt((1.0 / (l.Count - 1)) * (sum * sum))
```

Comment: @DStanley - Yeah, I realized that when I was typing my first 'fix'. Already changed it in the same way.

Comment: Thank you Henk, it appears I am too tired and sleepy to know my basic math today.